# Need help to understand this main() function in C

Tags: c

I'm learning C programming and do not quite understand the following program, need some help with the understanding.

Question 1: What do the two asterisks do preceding **argv in the main function parameters. 
Question 2: Inside the main() function, why void* is followed by an asterisk? What does it do?
Question 3: &retval has the "&", does the variable "retval" point to the memory address?

Thanks for help

```
 /** Main   */

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    pthread_t thread;
    void* retval;

    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_proc, NULL);

    printf("Hello from the main thread.\n");

    pthread_join(thread, &retval);
    printf("Done.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What learning material are you using? At this point you might want to first read about pointers – a very fundamental feature of C – and then ask specific questions if you don't understand them.

Comment: You'll find the answers in your text book. SO is not a substitute for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is somewhat confusing when starting to learn C.

Here are the basic principles that might help you get started:

1. There are only a few basic types in C:

   - `char`: an integer value with the size of 1 byte.
   - `short`: an integer value with the size of 2 bytes.
   - `long`: an integer value with the size of 4 bytes.
   - `long long`: an integer value with the size of 8 bytes.
   - `float`: a non-integer value with the size of 4 bytes.
   - `double`: a non-integer value with the size of 8 bytes.

   Note that the size of each type is generally defined by the compiler and **not by the standard.**

   The integer types `short`, `long` and `long long` are usually followed by `int`.

   It is not a must, however, and you can use them without the `int`.

   Alternatively, you can just state `int`, but that might be interpreted differently by different compilers.

   So to summarize this:

   - `short` is the same as `short int` but not necessarily the same as `int`.
   - `long` is the same as `long int` but not necessarily the same as `int`.
   - `long long` is the same as `long long int` but not necessarily the same as `int`.
   - On a given compiler, `int` is either `short int` or `long int` or `long long int`.
2. If you declare a variable of some type, then you can also declare another variable pointing to it.

   For example:

   `int a;`

   `int* b = &a;`

   So in essence, for each basic type, we also have a corresponding pointer type.

   For example: `short` and `short*`.

   There are two ways to "look at" variable `b` **(that's what probably confuses most beginners)**:

   - You can consider `b` as a variable of type `int*`.
   - You can consider `*b` as a variable of type `int`.

   Hence, some people would declare `int* b`, whereas others would declare `int *b`.

   But the fact of the matter is that these two declarations are identical (the spaces are meaningless).

   You can use either `b` as a pointer to an integer value, or `*b` as the actual pointed integer value.

   You can get (read) the pointed value: `int c = *b`.

   And you can set (write) the pointed value: `*b = 5`.
3. A pointer can point to any memory address, and not only to the address of some variable that you have previously declared. However, you must be careful when using pointers in order to get or set the value located at the pointed memory address.

   For example:

   `int* a = (int*)0x8000000;`

   Here, we have variable `a` pointing to memory address 0x8000000.

   If this memory address is not mapped within the memory space of your program, then any read or write operation using `*a` will most likely cause your program to crash, due to a memory access violation.

   You can safely change the value of `a`, but you should be very careful changing the value of `*a`.
4. Type `void*` is exceptional in the fact that it doesn't have a corresponding "value type" which can be used (i.e., you cannot declare `void a`). This type is used only as a general pointer to a memory address, without specifying the type of data that resides in that address.

Comment: Did you miss the "Note that the size of each type is generally defined by the compiler and not by the standard" statement at the end of the section which gives the size of each type???

Comment: Thank you, I see it now.  However, you might consider wanting to put that at the top of the section.

Answer (score 2):

Answer one :
char **argv mean you have a two dimension array of char.
you can access it like this :

```
argv[0][2]
```

it give you a char.
But you can access like this :

```
argv[0]
```

who give you a char *

Here, the '*' told that it's a pointer.
So it's not a char directly in your memory, but a case which will contain an address to char.
The fact to have int *; or char *; or anything * mean that you probably have an array.

Answer 2:
The void * is simple.
You have a pointer to something you don't know yet what it will be.
So a void * pointer can take address of any type of value like a char, a int, r more sophisticate type like system time (here, thread pointer).

Answer 3:
The '&' mean : take the address of this field.
So if I have

```
int i = 5;
printf("%i", i);
printf("%i", &i);
```

the first print will show the value of int : here 5.
The second will show you the address of i, here something like 0x06528A7
the fact with '&' is that you can do this :

```
int *ptr;
int i = 5;

ptr = &i;
```

you can now send your 'int *ptr' or another function, to modify it.
It will be too in the main.
Cause while modifying 'ptr', you are modifying 'i' and not a copy.
Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

`*` in c is used to declare pointers. A pointer is a variable that holds the location of, literally the address-of, a variable stored in computer memory.

So in your question `void* retval;` declare a void pointer.  A void pointer is a special type of pointer that can be pointed at objects of any data type!

```
char **argv
```

is a pointer to a pointer to char. Actually it is a variable that holds the address of a variable that is a pointer also

Answer (score 1):

`char** argv` is equivalent to `char **argv`, and roughly means

> A memory address value that when accessed, contains a memory address value which
>   when accessed contains a memory address value which contains the first char

C uses null terminated strings, so all that is needed to know the end of a string is the first memory address where it starts.  The rest of the routines then search subsequent addresses looking for the null `\0` character.

C also uses null terminated lists, so all that is needed to know the end of a list is the first memory address where the list starts (assuming you know the size of the list).  In this case, the list is of size `sizeof(*char)`, or in English "the size of a pointer to char".  The rest of the list traversing routines then search subsequent indexes in the list (subsequent memory offsets) until it is terminated by the null character.

Try to read it right to left, and it reads "a pointer to a pointer to a char", or in easier terms "a list of strings".

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a notation to mark `pointer` You should learn about pointers in `c`
1)By `char** argv`, **`argv`  is declared as a `pointer` to `pointer` to `char`**

2) By `void*`, it means **a variable that can hold address of any kind of variable**.

3) as `retval` is a pointer, it can point to a memory location. and by `&retval` you are getting address of the variable named `retval`.

**`&` is called the `address of` operator.**

Comment: Your answer would probably be *much* more useful if it answered the specific questions of the OP regarding the double pointer and the reference.